# Clear Interval when app is in background state in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to know how to clear an Interval whenever my app goes into Background State.

Sometimes when I click the Home button my application is being closed (willUnmount event is not fired) and then the interval is never cleared.

Answer (score 0):

How did you know the interval is never cleared if app closed?(Just curious) If App is being closed, it should be not working at all, isn't it? Only if you have background timer maybe will run?

But I think it should be stopped if you close the app?
I think in your case, you can use [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate) from react-native, to detect if app went back to foreground then reset the interval?

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import {
  AppState,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from "react-native";

export default class AppStateExample extends Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = nextAppState => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === "active"
    ) {
      console.log("App has come to the foreground!"); //reset interval here
    }
    this.setState({
      appState: nextAppState
    });
  };

  render() {
    return ( 
    <View style = {
        styles.container
      } >
      <Text>
      Current state is: {
        this.state.appState
      }</Text> 
    </View >
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});
```

Comment: Indeed the problem is solved using the AppState, thank you. How did I know the interval wasn't cleared? when I reopened the app, random things started to appear on my screen which indicated me the last interval wasn't cleared .

Comment: So it should cleared or initial the last interval to default when detect user back to fore screen. It's not cleared when it goes to background. So you will know if it cleared when it back and console?

Comment: i clear interval when i go to background state and restart it when detect user back but sometimes OS kills my application when in background and leaves js thread , so after i restart application the js thread detects user back and keeps old interval not good

Comment: Could you add a detect to clean the  thread when you starting the application like `componentDidMount()` ? And set the same as in back to fore screen. Then you can control the thread every time ?